# Is it illegal for a store to sell, schedule delivery and then don't have material?

Tags: contract-law, fraud

I purchased material from a store and set up delivery. They delivered part of it and said the balance was coming the next day. Then they rescheduled delivery date for the third time the next week. The rest of the material never came. Two weeks later they notified me they don't have the material and don't know when they will have it. Isn't this fraud?

Comment: Assuming you paid for this entire amount of material, have you requested a refund for the undelivered product?  This could be nothing but a mistake on their part.  They thought they had the material or were expecting it to be delivered and that didn't happen.  The bar for fraud is considerably higher.

Comment: The answer varies by jurisdiction. In the U.S. this is largely a question of state law.

Comment: What do their terms say about the possibility of canceling all or part of the order?

Comment: Almost certain that this is a duplicate and will try to find a prior answer.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on where you are, and likely also on what they knew when. It is entirely normal to order some goods (like perishable food, or custom-fitted furniture) before it is produced. The contract may or may not include advance payment. Most jurisdictions require some sort of *intent* for fraud, so the non-fulfillment would not be fraud if circumstances beyond the control of the supplier prevent delivery.

The question of civil damages and repayment is distinct from criminal fraud charges.